# python format spec for int.__format__

Tags: python

I have reason to want to call `int.__format__` directly. I tried the following

```
>>> object.__format__(1,'d')
```

But get an exception

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to int.__format__
```

What should the `fmt_spec` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you used `object.__format__` not `int.__format__`. Try one of these instead:

```
>>> int.__format__(1, 'd')
'1'
>>> (1).__format__('d')
'1'
```

The behaviour you're seeing with non-empty string passed to `object.__format__` is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__):

> *Changed in version 3.4:* The `__format__` method of object itself raises a [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) if passed any non-empty string.